# Converting sequence of lists to dictionary-python

Tags: python

I am scraping data from from website and till now ,I have converted to list of values .I want output in the form of dictionary where if user enters "open"-"39.30" will be displayed,if user enters "Previous close",then "39.79 " wil be displayed.So I converted text tag of str type into a list of values.How to convert these lists into a dictionary ?

```
website='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMD?p=AMD&.tsrc=fin-srch-v1'
htmltag = urllib.request.urlopen(website).read()
soups = BeautifulSoup(htmltag,'lxml')
allidtag = soups.find('div', id='YDC-Col1')
alll=allidtag.find_all('table', class_='W(100%)')
for item in alll:
    tablerow=item.find_all('tr')  #I have collected all the tr tags 
    for i in tablerow:
        s=i.find_all('td')#I have found td tags
        for j in s:
            a=j.text   #extracted the span tags
            b=a.split(" ")  #converting to lists
            print(b)
```

```
['Previous', 'Close']
['39.79']
['Open']
['39.30']
['Bid']
['39.03', 'x', '3200']
['Ask']
['39.07', 'x', '1100']
["Day's", 'Range']
['38.83', '-', '39.48']
['52', 'Week', 'Range']
['16.03', '-', '41.79']
['Volume']
['42,197,133']
['Avg.', 'Volume']
['52,798,084']
['Market', 'Cap']
['44.394B']
```

If i print "a" alone,then output of str type occurs:

```
Previous Close
39.79
Open
39.30
Bid
39.03 x 4000
Ask
39.07 x 1200
Day's Range
38.82 - 39.48
52 Week Range
16.03 - 41.79
Volume
42,197,133
Avg. Volume
52,798,084
Market Cap
44.394B
Beta (3Y Monthly)
3.06
PE Ratio (TTM)
204.14
EPS (TTM)
0.19
Earnings Date
Jan 27, 2020 - Jan 31, 2020
Forward Dividend & Yield
N/A (N/A)
Ex-Dividend Date
1995-04-27
1y Target Est
35.57
```

Comment: I think we need your `alll` for reproducibility.

Comment: I would strongly recommend querying an API for this, instead of scraping the data from the HTML. If you write your code which depends on the exact HTML formatting of the page Yahoo sends you, then your program will break every time they change the formatting of it. An API returns the data in a format designed to be used by programs: see e.g. https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd completely remove the last `for` loop with something like this:

```py
key = s[0].get_text()
value = s[1].get_text()
d[key] = value
```

Returns:

```
{'Previous Close': '39.79', 'Open': '39.30', 'Bid': '39.03 x 3200', 'Ask': '39.15 x 1100', "Day's Range": '38.83 - 39.48', '52 Week Range': '16.03 - 41.79', 'Volume': '42,197,133', 'Avg. Volume': '52,798,084', 'Market Cap': '44.394B', 'Beta (3Y Monthly)': '3.06', 'PE Ratio (TTM)': '204.14', 'EPS (TTM)': '0.19', 'Earnings Date': 'Jan 27, 2020 - Jan 31, 2020', 'Forward Dividend & Yield': 'N/A (N/A)', 'Ex-Dividend Date': '1995-04-27', '1y Target Est': '35.57'}
```

You don't need to loop through the `td` elements since they're in a predictable order. And I don't see a need to split the strings into lists either because it just makes more sense to keep them together.

Comment: You just have to look at the page source. Each `tr` has exactly two `td` elements the first one being descriptor and the second being the value. The `find_all` method puts the elements into a list in the order that they appear.

Comment: That worked.....I never thought of s[0] and s[1]...that was helpful.....But can you please let me know how did u find out that s[0] will give the first text and s[1] will give the second one.

Comment: @suchitranagarajan It’s basic indexing. I **strongly recommend** studying the basics of programming and Python more, before attempting anything else.